# What is the best way to show a page only on first visit with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using this code to show the `splashscreen` only when the user is visiting the app for the first time. This works, partially, but it's not working properly.

**When a user, who has already visited the app before, visits again, it first shows the splashscreen for just 1 second (so a delay), before it (eventually)  goes to the home screen... so it's like a glitch.**

Main controller:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");
```

In my *splashscreen controller*, I have this:

```
  if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
        localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
        $state.go('splash'); 
    }
    else {
        $state.go('home');
    }
```

So probably I am doing something wrong here and I want to know how can I show a page just once (on first visit!) and not anymore...

Comment: Are you removing `firstTimeLoad` from `localStorage` or setting it to `false` anywhere?

Comment: Nope, this is the only code I use...

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the code. It looks like you send the person back to splash screen from the splash screen. The second time they are at splash screen it looks like they will go to home, but you still have to hit it twice for that to happen.

Comment: First, we have a main controller. In the maincontroller, I automatically send them to the splash screen first. In the splash controller, however, I check whether it's the first time they are visiting. If not, I send them to the home page. It's not the best code, that's why I am trying to improve it and need some help. And now, I just see a glitch when someone is directed to the homepage, meaning: I see the splash screen for 1 second after it redirects to the homepage, so I don't think I am sending the person back to the splash screen... or maybe I am. It confuses me too at the moment.

Comment: You say the code above is in the splash screen controller. But shouldn't it be in the main controller? The splash screen should then send the user to another page after it's finished showing whatever it has to show.

Comment: In my post, I have written down the places I have put them. The first snippet is in the main controller. The second snippet is in the splash controller. I don't know if that's correct, but it sure does something when I do it like that. The only problem I have right now, is the glitch... I am close, but not there yet and that's a bit sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that is currently in your splashscreen controller might belong in your Main controller:

```
  if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
        localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
        $state.go('splash'); 
    }
    else {
        $state.go('home');
    }
```

If the code above were in your splash screen controller, whenever the user gets to the splash screen for the first time it would send them back to the splash screen. Then the second time it would send them to Home (but you're still starting from the splash screen, so maybe there is still a delay before you send them to Home?).

Also, it seems like the code that is currently in your Main controller should be in your routes file:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/splash");
```

**Edit:** According to the comments, there is no Main controller (that is what you call your route provider). So the redirect logic could go in your Home controller. But if you want to keep it in your splash screen controller, I assume there is a `setTimeout` in there - where is it located? It looks like your logic needs to be something like this:

```
if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
    localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';

    $timeout(function() {
        // Show the current splash screen for some time, then redirect
        $state.go('home'); 
    }, delayTimeInMilliseconds);
}
else {
    $state.go('home');
}
```

But we may be able to provide better help if you show more code.

**Edit:** The code above works for me, but since it executes in the splash screen controller, even if the second branch of the `if` statement executes (causing an immediate redirect to `home`) the splash screen could still render and display for a fraction of a second before the redirect completes. A quick workaround could be to set a variable `showSplashScreen`:

```
if (localStorage['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
    localStorage['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';

    $scope.showSplashScreen = true;

    $timeout(function() {
        // Show the current splash screen for some time, then redirect
        $state.go('home'); 
    }, delayTimeInMilliseconds);
}
else {
    $state.go('home');
}
```

And then use `ng-if = "showSplashScreen"` on the outermost 
element of your splash screen template. Otherwise, the redirect logic should be moved elsewhere (perhaps into the router itself, as a `resolve` property on the Home route or a parent route, or even in the Home controller) so that you never even get to the splash screen controller if the user has already been to the site.

Comment: What exactly is a main controller? Because my main controller IS the splash screen... as that is the first page. What is your definition of a main controller?

Comment: Your question seemed phrased as though the main controller and the splash screen controller are two different things. Also, in your comment you said "The first snippet is in the main controller. The second snippet is in the splash controller." Maybe you can show more code.

Comment: I get what you mean... the main controller is just the $ionicConfigProvider / state provider. I call that the main controller, but don't know if that's your definition as well.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks. So, I should put the last snippet you sent in my splash controller and that's it? Beside that: no, I have no timeout there; why would I need that? Can you explain?

Comment: By the way, I can see the splashscreen still when I use your code... it just shows up for like 1 second, even if I set the delay to 0. So it did not solve my problem, because that was my problem...

Comment: I thought maybe you were leaving them on the splash screen for a certain period of time, using a timeout. Maybe you shouldn't send them to the splash screen at all if they have already visited the site. But I thought sending them there and redirecting them to home immediately (not using a timeout - as I did in the second branch of the `if` statement) would work. At this point I need more code or a live example, because I am making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: What I want to achieve: I want people to get to the splash screen if and only if it is there first time checking the app, ever. When they check the app the second time, I don't want the splash screen to show up EVER. And, this is the only code I am using for them, nothing more. I thought it would be simple, but it seems like it isn't.

Comment: Frank, I thank you for your efforts. I accepted the answer, even though I have not tested it yet. I will test it and try it later on. Cheers! Oh and: yes, there is a home controller I am using, yet there is nothing regarding this code that I am using or checking there when someone is redirected. That's why I did not share it. So if there is a trick I can use in the home controller: please tell me!

Comment: You're welcome. What I meant was I assume there is a state/route definition for Home somewhere, like `$stateProvider.state('home', { url: "/home", templateUrl: ' ... '  })` that wasn't being shown. Perhaps the way it is defined influences what you are seeing. Also, the logic that checks localStorage and redirects to the splash controller might be better placed in the resolve property of the Home state/route definition, or even in the Home controller. Let me know what you end up doing!

Comment: Yes, I have exactly what you have written there and I link to it via "/home", so yes, I have that... I thought it was not relevant, because the snippet I am using was not being used in the home controller. What do you suggest? To put the code you made in home controller instead?

Comment: Yes I think putting the logic in the Home controller would work. But it would have to be the very first snippet of code at the top of my answer, which is essentially what you started with. The only potential issue is that if you hit the Home controller and then redirect to the splash screen, you may still see the Home page for a fraction of a second before you get to the splash screen. So it's the reverse of the previous issue, but seems better. Pushing the redirect logic higher into the Home route itself could be even better. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I will try this asap! I am wondering though: is this the only way this is possible? So, there is not a possibility to get rid of the frustrating glitch, ever?

Comment: Putting the logic in the `resolve` property of the Home route definition would probably be best. Then you could decide whether to go to the splash screen even before Home has rendered. Check out the ui-router docs for more information on route configuration.